# Удаление файла после создания

Tags: c#

Делаю скриншот таким образом:

```
public static Bitmap BM = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
...
Graphics GH = Graphics.FromImage(BM as Image);
GH.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, BM.Size);

BM.Save("D:\\dir\\screen.jpg");
...
File.Delete("D:\\dir\\screen.jpg");
```

При запуске программы вылетает ошибка, мол файл используется другим процессом
Как исправить ошибку?

**UPD:** Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В C# не разбираюсь, но подозреваю, что нужно закрыть стрим.

Answer (score 4):

Ваша программа лочит файл, отпустите его, а потом удаляйте

```
using(var BM = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
{
    ...
    var GH = Graphics.FromImage(BM as Image);
    GH.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, BM.Size);
    BM.Save("D:\\dir\\screen.jpg");
}
```

далее можете удалять

```
File.Delete("D:\\dir\\screen.jpg");
```

Comment: Ошибка осталась

Comment: @andrew добавте в вопрос ошибку которая у вас выдается

Comment: [Вот](http://goo.gl/UzBak4)

Comment: @andrew, вы точно используете код как я тут привел? или же внесли свои правки? после выхода из using обычно файл освобождается и его можно `удалить`/`переместить`/`открыть` и тд

Comment: @andrew, и да, хранить даже временно файлы в системной папке Windows не безопастно

Comment: @Dmitry - небезопастно и вредоностно :)

Comment: @Dmitry, да, я поменял так, как вы написали, ошибка всё та же.  
Я знаю, что опасно, так надо

Comment: @andrew, смотрите в дебагере, что еще может держать файл. Ну и весьма конкретный вопрос, а вы его случайно ни чем просматривать не пытаетесь? и совет, попробуйте сохранить файл в папку c:\temp. Вполне может статься, что антивирус к примеру делает снипшет с вашего файла пока вы его пытаетесь удалять